# Cycles render layers - make overlapping parts transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers

I am using Blender Cycles to render the following 2 layers:

[image: layer 1]

[image: layer 2]

However, I would like the overlapping parts in image 2 (see arrows) to be transparent, not black. I have already searched for many things here (alpha over, mask layer, etc), but I still don't know what I need to do exactly in order to make those black parts transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your two layers are **House** and **Grass**:

[image]

House will look like this:

[image]

This says that all the objects in the scene are on layers `1` and `2`, the house is on layer `1`, and it should be covered up by layer `2` (the grass).

Grass will look like this:

[image]

This says that all the objects in the scene are on layers `1` and `2`, and the grass is on layer `2`.

Comment: @GlimpseIdea Glad I could help! Please accept the answer if it solved the problem :-).